# Provide Hadoop full access to Admin from Root in CentOS

Tags: linux, hadoop, centos, centos7

I have installed Hadoop-2.8.0 being root in below directory.

> /root/hadoop-2.8.0

I have a user named "KrishnaMahi". He is admin. He is in below directory.

> /home/krishnamahi

I want to provide full access of Hadoop to admin. How shall I provide full access to admin without giving root password? I am using CentOS 7. Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the root user  execute the following command

```
 chown -R krishnamahi:krishnamahi /root/hadoop-2.8.0
```

and then  execute the next command  to   be  the root user without password

```
visudo
```

Insert  this code  at the last line

```
krishnamahi ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD:ALL
```

save changes & exit

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following once command

```
sudo chown -R krishnamahi:krishnamahi /root/hadoop-2.8.0
```

Then the user have full access to the hadoop directory.